# How can internet speed test applet not just show slow speed, but hang?

Tags: networking, performance, freeze

I have one internet connection, which works bad. It should be 80/20, but works much slower. Also, when measuring it's speed, speed test applet not just show slow speed, but HANG.

How can it be hanging?

Video recording is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOHnbTJ28R4

As you see, after starting test at 0:10 it was hanging, then jumped to 30 at 0:23, then doing normal measure, then figures were starting to roll slower and slower and at the end arrow was apparently sticking to it's positions.

Why? Which network problem can cause this behavior? Packet loss? Temporary cable disconnecting? What?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your upload Speed is 0.51Mbps, or 510Kbps, so try this:

Open command prompt and do a continuous ping to Google.com by typing in:

```
ping www.google.com -t
```

You use the `-t` switch for an untimed ping, and the way to stop it is to Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, or just exit the shell/command line.

Run the ping test first, then keep it running and post another video that shows
the command line pinging Google.com while you run the speed test concurrently.

Then we will see if it drops out or if it's your upload speed or if it's a resistant issue.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This probably were problems with my DryaTek Vigor 2920Vn. I have downgraded it's firmware and may problems disappeared, including this one.

Comment: Possibly, But, if you did the test that i asked you to do, we would see this, You see if that test showed problems that i would ask you to open cmd.exe and type in   ipconfig  and get your gateway IP Address, then , let's say it's 192.168.1.1   then you would do this    ping 192.168.1.1  and if the same problems are there, then we know it's a problem with either Your NIC, (Network interface card) the Cable or the modem,  the cable you can test with a cable tester or simply replace the cable, and the rest goes from there.  any other questions?

Comment: No, thanks a lot! I killed a lot of time fighting with this scrap-metal. May be try newer firmware later and see how it behaves simultaneously with ping.

Comment: Sounds good, Let me know if you need any further help, just so you understand ping and how to interpret the results,  You mainly looking for a nice steady ping from ping to ping, as for the time in ms this is important, as a general rule if the number is higher than 150ms it's a concern, if it's higher than 300ms that's bad,  if it's 1000ms or above really bad,  Now, High time=ms is as a result of resistance on the line, something that opposes the flow of data, could be hardware, it would be water in the phone line, it could be a lot of things, but. ultimately it's a RESISTANCE issue be cool

Comment: One last thing, it's normal for the resistance to go up really high during the speedtest, because that's a huge LOAD on the line, but.. it's not normal for it to dropout, if it does call your ISP and tell them to do a LINE TEST and see whats going on with your phone line, or it could be Profile Shaping from the service providers end, but i doubt it , in your case. Take CAre

Comment: Thankyou HopelessNoob for making sure that i use Uppecase for the first letter, Don't you think you went a little overboard with the Edit request, and incidentally, it's not called   "the COMMAND LINE pinging Google"  it's a COMMAND SHELL  The Interface Type itself is a Command Line Interface, But What your using is a CLI Shell , so Please don't take it upon yourself to correct my grammar in situations like this, the only edit that you did that i agree with is the   ping www.google.com -t  part  i can see why you edited that, the Uppercase thing and rewording,is you nitpicking.

Comment: and i don't think it's fair that i get a down vote for you nitpicking things that don't really matter, especially if you don't know that cmd.exe Opens a Shell, Regardless of your su status,  I have 13 Years Engineering experience, What are your qualifications, I Would Kindly ask you to change the wording back to what it was, reword command Line to reflect Command Shell, You can leave the rest as is, if you like